# Enhanced VLOOKUP formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following sheet structure:

[image]

What I need to find out is, whether code **8101-1101** contains any **Matching Projects** (in our case 9500-1100). I have tried VLOOKUP formula, however that only works if the matching project is set to the very first item. If matching project exists only somewhere in the middle, then the formula fails. I have also tried SUMIF yet with no luck.

What formula do I need to use, to check this particular example?

Comment: Look into `COUNTIFS()` - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Comment: Could you help me a bit? I tried the following but it did not work: =COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,I:I,"<>""")

Comment: Where do you need this? A new column?

Comment: I am using this in a different sheet to retrieve boolean value (if exists then result is TRUE, if not then FALSE)

Comment: Just try this `=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,I:I,"<>")` - Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Make it an answer, fantastic!

Comment: @JohnBustos - does  the `"<>"` just mean ...not equal? I see it's pretty much the equivalent of `"<>"""`, but how come yours works, but the "not equal to blank" doesn't? I thought Robert's attempt would have done it - why didn't it work?

Comment: @BruceWayne It looks like Robert's attempt just needed the & after the "<>", like so:=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,I:I,"<>"&""). Yes, <> means "Not Equal To", and appending a "" after it does resolves into the same thing [Not Equal to ""].

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon - Ah, I get that now, thanks.  How come though the `"<>""""` doesn't work the same way? Is it mainly the multiple quotes being used that Excel doesn't like too much?

Comment: When Excel sees multiple ""'s in a row, it attempts to insert a literal " into a string. ie: \\\="""Hi"" he said"\\\ tells Excel to output the string \\\"Hi" he said\\\. So you don't actually want the " in the COUNTIFS, you just want the <>.

Comment: I posted it as a final solution, but just glad you got it working, man! - Also, good call on the `& ""` @Grade'Eh'Bacon, that would accomplish the same outcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, the easiest way to accomplish what you're looking to do would be using the [`COUNTIFS()` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842).

Given your example, your final formula would be as follows:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,B2,I:I,"<>")
```

Good luck and glad it ended up working for you!!